# Uploading file to Google App Engine using new dev_appserver

Tags: python, google-app-engine, file-upload

[Google App Engine documentation](https://developers.google.com/appengine/docs/python/images/usingimages) makes it appear very simple to get the contents of an uploaded file (`self.request.get('user_file')`), but while I can do this with old_dev_appserver.py, I cannot get it with the current dev_appserver.py (v1.9.2).

Here's a simple example that generates the incoming data:

```
<form name="myform" action="http://localhost:8080/sync?cmd=tester" enctype="multipart/form-data" method="post">
    Username: <input type="file" name="user_file" />
    <input type="submit" value="Submit" />
</form>
```

- In old_dev_appserver.py, one could get the file in GAE via `self.request.get('user_file')`, but not with the latest (1.9.2) dev_appserver.py
- [WebApp2 says](http://webapp-improved.appspot.com/guide/request.html#files) "Uploaded files are available as cgi.FieldStorage (see the cgi module) instances directly in request.POST."  But, `request.POST` is empty, and `cgi.FieldStorage()` does not contain 'user_file' either.

Strangely, if I print out `self.request.params`, I do see an element in the UnicodeMultiDict that is `(u'user_file', FieldStorage(u'user_file', u'myfile.ico'))`.  But when I try to get that element, either via named access or just iterating over params, I cannot get it.  Even if I do a `Len(self.request.params)` I get one less than what I see, and the 'user_file' element is missing.  If I do this with old_dev_appserver, the `Len(self.request.params)` is correct.

How do I get user_file?

Answer (score 0):

Figured it out (finally!).  I had been logging elements of the request (params, body, etc.) as I sorted through other issues.  But you can only instantiate a `cgi.FieldStorage` element once, so by the time I got to the actual `self.request.get('user_file')`, it was already gone.

Classic case in which removing the debugging actually makes it work.